# Movies on DVD, how?

Tags: dvd

I want to put a movie on a DVD and then watch them on my T.V. how can I do that? When I put a movie on a DVD and then put it on my T.V it can't read it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

First of all download the codecs if you have not already

sudo apt-get install libdvdcss libdvdread4 libdvdnav4

Then i would goto the software centre and download Devede :D

Answer (score 0):

Download the software that helps you to burn DVD

[OpenShot](http://www.openshotvideo.com/) has more features, simple, easy to use interface.

[DeVeDe](http://www.rastersoft.com/programas/devede.html)good program for writing videos to DVD (With support for titles and menus).

Both of these applications are available to install from the Ubuntu Software Centre.

Use this application to write files on DVD and hopefully you will be able to watch it if your DVD player supports the codec of your movie.

Answer (score 0):

I do this by using DeVeDe to create a DVD disk image, then Brasero to burn the image to disk. Both apps are in the Software Centre.

I've tried doing the whole thing with Brasero, but it didn't work.

However Brasero seems better at estimating the size on disk of the content. So my recommendation is to make a DVD project in Brasero to check the content fits well on the disk, then start again in DeVeDe ignoring any complaints that the content is too big. Make the image then go back to Brasero to burn that image to disk.